# How to prove Shortest Common Superstring is NP-Hard

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics, proof, deterministic, non-deterministic

After some research and many youtube videos I have learnt that to prove a problem is *NP-Hard*; you would need to reduce that problem to known NP-Hard problems such as Subset Sum Problem, Halting Problem, Satisfiability Problem or Traveling Salesman Problem. Now my problem is **Shortest Common Superstring**

- **Input:** A finite set R = {r1, r2, ..., rm} of binary strings (sequences of 0 and 1); positive
  integer k.
- **Question:** Is there a binary string w of length at most k such that every string in R
  is a substring of w, i.e. for each r in R, w can be decomposed as w = w0rw1 where w0,
  w1 are (possibly empty) binary strings?

In this link it states that the problem is NP-Hard(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-superstring-problem/), besides I am using the greedy algorithm stated there to solve the problem.

So I need help with choosing which NP-Hard Algorithm to reduce to and a way to reduce it. I do not expect a full solution(even though it would be welcome), just guidance would be enough.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. It might fit in better at: https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I would suggest https://cs.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: https://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBAfl/VT06/algorithms/BOOK/BOOK5/NODE209.HTM